# in matplotlib the offset of the scientific notation in xaxis stays at bottom when axis is set to top

Tags: python, matplotlib, format, axis

the power indicator of an xaxis set to top stays on the bottom axis

I have seen that for the yaxis you have a function 
`ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')`, but I could not find any equivalent for the xaxis.

here is an example of the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

datay = np.arange(20)

datax = np.random.random(20) * 1.e-4
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(datax,datay,c='k')
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2)) 

data2x = np.random.random(20) * 1.e-4
bx = ax.twiny()
bx.plot(data2x,datay,c='r')
bx.ticklabel_format(axis='x', style='sci', scilimits=(-2,2)) 

plt.show()
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHl0q.png)

Comment: That is a really weird oversight in the API, please create a GH issue requesting it.

Comment: ok, posted [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5238)

Comment: poking at this a bit, there is a bunch of mess here, xoffsets are hard-coded to be on the bottom, y-offets are hard-coded to be on the top.  It is easy to add left/right to the xaxis, but top/bottom + left/right will require much more major changes to the `Axis` family